# Using R to copy files based on a vector

Tags: r, vector, copy

I've found a few related posts but nothing that quite gets at my problem:

I want to copy files based on whether a portion of the file name matches a vector. The following only returns the first match in the vector, not each match

```
vector_key<- c(12345, 54321)

list.files("C:/Userfiles")
```

Where the user files include "12345.pdf" , "54321.pdf" "32.pdf" and "23.pdf", among about 200 other files.

```
files<- list.files("C:/Userfiles",  full.names= TRUE, pattern = vector_key)
print files
```

This prints the first match but not the second

"C:/Userfiles/12345.pdf" but not "C:/Userfiles/54321/pdf"

I'd appreciate any help on how to list.files and match on ALL patterns in the vector_key, not just the first match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need `pattern` as a single string.  According to `?list.files`

> pattern - an optional regular expression. Only file names which match the regular expression will be returned.

Here, the `|` is a metacharacter signifying `OR` in regex

```
pat <- paste(vector_key, collapse = "|")
list.files("C:/Userfiles",  full.names= TRUE, pattern = pat)
```

---

Also, if it is to get all the files with the `.pdf`, then just usee

```
list.files("C:/Userfiles", full.names = TRUE, pattern = "^\\d+\\.pdf")
```

where `\\d+` - one or more digits followed by a `.` (`.` - is a metacharacter that matches any character, so it should be either escaped (`\\`) or placed in square brackets (`[.]` to evaluate literally)

Comment: Thank you! In this instance I need to exclude some PDFs but the collapse into OR worked perfectly.

Comment: @EricSchroer Thanks.  If the patterns can be showed in a general pattern like `pattern = "^[0246]+\\.pdf"` i.e. one or more digits of 0, 2, 4, 6 while excluding others.  But, I think you need to have a vector if the combinations are there